# PHP while loop issue

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, limit

I have PHP script contains a long loop to list about 60,000 email addresses from mysql, but after 30,000, my php script stops working and brakes, and sometimes all php script is written in white page (my page has imaged background), I increased PHP memory limit to unlimited, but no help.
What's problem?

Comment: As other users said - try "max_execution_time", if it not help - it can be memory issue. Try to output memory_get_usage on every 1000 iteration and compare with your server ram

Comment: I set set_time_limit to 5000 then 0, no help
Last number I got after 33,138th email address is 332032 bytes (325 kb), my server has 2GB RAM.

Comment: what about ignore_user_abort ?

Comment: I set it to false, no help.

Comment: khmm....what apache error log says to you ? what about error_reporting inside your php script

Comment: did you invoke your script through cli ?

Comment: error_reporting shows nothing for today, it contains only old errors for past days, not sure what cli is, I'm only using simple while loop.

Comment: I used SSH to run my php page, all 60,000 email addresses are listed in SSH console, but in browsers, it shows only about 30,000.

Comment: Probably the problem in your server, especially "php_admin_value max_execution_time 1000" setting may occur, try set time limit and next line display this setting by ini_get('max_execution_time')

Comment: Tried that, I got 0, I guess this issue remains a mystery, anyway, I changed my while loop to save email addresses in one text file using fwrite, and prints nothing in my php page, and this one is working for me, I got all emails in text file.

Answer (score 2):

The default execution time limit is 30 seconds, or the *max_execution_time* value from php.ini. Is your script taking longer than that? If so, you can increase the limit with [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

The better question is, what are you doing with 60,000 email addresses that is taking so long? Chances are, there is a much better way to do whatever is taking too long.

Comment: I set set_time_limit to 5000 then 0, no help.
My script only takes 5 seconds to load.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in memory I think it's in Time for execution

```
set_time_limit(VERY_BIG_NUMBER);
```

**Update:**

add

```
    ini_set("display_errors","on");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and inspect errors if any

Comment: I set set_time_limit to 5000 then 0, no help.
My script only takes 5 seconds to load.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can try here. Firstly, [`set_time_limit(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). Setting it to zero means there is essentially no time limit.

Secondly you might want to use [`ignore_user_abort(false)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php). This will et whether a client disconnect should abort script execution.

Both will ensure that your script keeps running for as long as it needs... or until your server packs out :)

Answer (score 0):

check "max_execution_time"

How long does the script run before breaking? 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_time_limit()` and increase the max execution time for the script.